Avoiding Google Authenticator Re-Authentication for Existing SSH Sessions on EC2
I've configured Google Authenticator for 2FA on my Almalinux 9 EC2 instance to secure SSH access. However, I'm prompted for the Google Authenticator code every time I open a new SSH session, even when a previous session is already active. This repeated authentication is cumbersome. Ideally, I'd like to avoid re-authentication for additional SSH sessions while a valid session remains open.
I've checked the PAM configuration for Google Authenticator on the server, but haven't found any options related to session management. Also there is a method called SSH multiplexing to address this issue. But that method needs to be implemented on client side. Not on remote server side.
How can I configure Google Authenticator or my SSH server on the EC2 instance to avoid re-authentication for subsequent SSH sessions while an existing session is active, focusing entirely on server-side configuration?

How would the server know that the new session is initiated by the same person?
